# Reducing the console output of LaTeX

Tags: compiling, debugging

When I run pdfLaTeX, I get very verbose output:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex)
...
```

Is there a script to soak up all the verbose output and allow the important stuff to pass through, like errors, overfull hboxes, and so on?

Also, is there a reason why it sends a hard return to the console for lines longer than 79 characters?

Comment: This is not a pdfLaTeX thing: the file comments are TeX itself, and so you get them with all of the engines.

Comment: @JosephWright: I don't think the (presumably renamed) {[tag:latex-project]} was appropriate, but I don't know which `tex` tag belongs here. Could you please add it (and get rid of then-obsolete comments)?

Comment: Regarding the second part of the question: A separate question is [available](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52988/avoid-linebreaks-in-latex-console-log-output)

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198583/post-filtering-output-that-i-cant-seem-to-pre-filter-with-silence-package

Comment: @BenCrowell: duplicate?

Comment: There is also [`texfot`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165518/15665), which is included in various distributions nowadays.

Comment: pdflatex filename.tex >> info_filename.log

Comment: I use `tmux` to have a separate terminal pane just for compiling. I often have three panes: one for the TeX document in Vim, one for compiling, and another for actually using the command line that won't be junked up by TeX log output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modern solution is [latexmk](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/).

Comment: Is there any intermediate between -silent and -verbose?

Comment: @JoëlMeyer-Hamme I have no idea.  Perhaps make another question?

Comment: I'll keep looking. --interaction=batchmode looked promising but suppresses all warnings.

Comment: @JoëlMeyer-Hamme You could use and maybe modify an output parser like pplatex listed as another answer here.

Comment: [errors - Use latexmk to filter the log file - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10558/use-latexmk-to-filter-the-log-file) ... but it doesn't have *any*  solution that too late uses `latexmk`.

Answer (score 35):

The line feed after 79 characters is defined in Web2C's configuration file, called texmf.cnf.  The variable name is `max_print_line` which you can change in the file (not recommended in general, but in that case the setting is *really* harmless); and if you run TeX from a shell you can also set this variable in the environment (`export max_print_line=1048576` for Korn-like shells, `set max_print_line 1048576` for C shells).

I am not aware of a way to forbid line breaks entirely; I only set the variable to a very large value when this behaviour annoys me.

Comment: (Note: this is the answer to (only) the "also" part of the question. For the answer to the main question, see other answers below.)

Comment: This does not seem to work with lualatex

Comment: Recent versions of bibtex now read the `max_print_line` environment variable and report `3 is a bad bad` if it is >= 20000, the hard-coded initial value of `BUF_SIZE`. https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/bibtex.ch?r1=63237&r2=63238&

Answer (score 25):

The solution is

1. Either use the `-interaction batchmode` switch or put `\batchmode` at the start of the document(or anywhere you want to stop displaying output).
2. Use `\scrollmode`, `\nonstopmode`, or `\errorstopmode` anywhere you want to enable output generation. `\errorstopmode` enables errors interaction.
3. Use `\batchmode` anywhere you want to disable output generation.

   - To reduce clutter use the command line switch, and use the following template.

>

```
     \begin{document}
     \scrollmode
     ....
     \batchmode
     \end{document}
```

This will only show output from latex between the the `\scrollmode` and `\batchmode` and very little else.

---

If you are using WinEdt(or possibly some other automated process) it seems to like to open 0 length pdf's for no reason. It also doesn't seem to have an easy way to check for 0 length files.

- Add the follow to the `ExecCompiler.edt` file in the **\Exec** directory right after the string "// Check if the Output was Generated ...". (It is near the bottom)

> ExecCompiler.edt

```
Run('DeleteFileIfEmpty.exe "%P\%N.pdf"','%P',0,0,'%N.pdf',0,0,1);
IfFileExists("%P\%N.pdf", "Relax;", !"JMP('Exit');");
```

- Here is C code of for a simple tool that deletes a file if it is empty.

> DeleteFileIfEmpty.cpp

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

long GetFileSize(const TCHAR *fileName)
{    
    WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fileInfo;
    if (NULL == fileName) return -1;
    if (!GetFileAttributesEx(fileName, GetFileExInfoStandard, (void*)&fileInfo)) return -1;
    return (long)fileInfo.nFileSizeLow;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &argc); if (argc < 2) return -1;

    _TCHAR *fn = new _TCHAR[1000]; ZeroMemory(fn, 1000*sizeof(_TCHAR)); _TCHAR *fn2 = fn; 
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) { _tcscpy(fn2, argv[i]); fn2 += _tcslen(argv[i]); _tcscpy(fn2++, _T(" ")); } fn2--;
    if (GetFileSize(fn) > 0) return -1;

    DeleteFile(fn);
    return 1;
}
```

You can download this file at

http://www.freefilehosting.net/deletefileifempty

Put the DeleteFileIfEmpty.exe in a path that is in the %path% environment or the bin dir that WinEdt is setup to use.

---

This was tested with WinEdt6 and works. Reduces output clutter(no package loading msgs, banners, etc...) and doesn't open up empty files when there is an error.

Comment: This is a great solution. You can put `\batchmode` whenever you want to get rid of messages and `\scrollmode` whenever you want to see the warnings and other staffs.

Comment: At least MikTeX requires the commandline parameter to be `-interaction=batchmode` (no whitespace separator).

Comment: but `-interaction batchmode` also do not show compile errors! which is not good.

Answer (score 20):

This is what the [silence](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence) package is intended to help with.

Comment: This is great, thank you.  Do you know how to get rid of this stuff, though?

(/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))

Comment: That's TeX: it tells you what files its using. I've never seen a way to turn it off.

Comment: +1, could you add a little more information to this answer? E.g. an example of filtered output (if that makes any sense) or just quote the short CTAN package description.

Comment: @martin-heller Hi, I'm new to LaTeX, could be please an example for how to use it ?

Comment: @SebMa please see the documentation: http://texdoc.net/pkg/silence . Simply call `\WarningsOff[package]` after loading the `silence` package to eliminate warnings from `package`.

Answer (score 20):

[Rubber](https://launchpad.net/rubber/) has (among other things) some filtering capabilities, and generally gives errors in a very compressed form. You can also tell it to give you only certain kinds of warnings using `--warn=`.

Comment: I haven't installed this yet, but I'll mark this as correct after I try it out.

Comment: Please fix the link: http://rubber.sf.net/

Comment: @Jukka: Fixed it.

Comment: Works great.  I had to manually install it because macports wanted to install a full tex install as a dependency.

Comment: @Neil: MacPorts pulled this one on me last year when it decided that MacTeX 2009 was not good enough and I really needed 1 GB of TeX Live 2007 installed on my system.  Its existence was subsequently terminated with extreme prejudice.  Checkout [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) if you are interested in a package manager that strives to avoid these shenanigans.

Comment: Is it not true that rubber is fairly outdated? No release since 2006-03-17. I think mklatex is the way to go by now.

Comment: Wow, Rubber is absolutely perfect! I also noticed it wasn't updated for a while, but who cares if everything works :). And it has support for absolutely every configuration I want to do!

Comment: I'd recommend using [latexmk](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) being also part of MikTex and Texlive.

Comment: @jmc: people are still coming to this question.  It would be good to accept latexmk as the modern answer.  Would you mind adding it?  Maybe link here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/

Comment: @NeilG — Feel free to do it yourself. (Currently I don't have the inspiration for a good review/recommendation of latexmk. But maybe later this week.) Also, I am in the process of studying arara (better late then never), and I have the feeling that it might deserve mention in an answer to this question. Currently I do not have the expertise yet to write a good answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why people call rubber outdated. The latest release is 2015-12 as I write this, which is fairly recent.

Answer (score 11):

In order to neatly format the output, I created my own solution: [pydflatex](https://github.com/olivierverdier/pydflatex).
You would compile a file with

```
pydflatex myfile.tex
```

And get an output along the lines of

[image: pydflatex run]

On top of giving a neat, condensed output, it will also hide the auxilliary files, so as not to clutter your folder.

**Edit** It is now also possible to run

```
pydflatex -l file.tex
```

which will parse an existing log without typesetting.

Comment: This looks pretty nice Olivier! However, I personally would prefer a more UNIX-like "one tool, one task" philosophy. So is it possible to get the output formatting only (without all that wrapper and cons stuff). That is, get a similar output by `pdflatex file | pyformat` or  `cat file.log | pyformat`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... what you describe is what pydflatex does, just typeset a document with `pydflatex doc.tex` instead of `pdflatex doc.tex | pyformat`. You will get a similar result. So `pydflatex` does only the formatting. (Independently from pydflatex, I advocate using `scons` to ensure that pdfLaTeX will be run sufficiently many times, the bibliography will be built, etc.)

Comment: I do not want to use another tool for the typesetting, just for the output formatting, so I can easily plug it in existing generation processes (based on makefiles, different tex engines, ...). So in fact my process is `some-tool-that-produces-pdflatex-like-log-output | pyformat`. Furthermore, it would be great to filter already generate log files through it, that is, be able to do a `cat file.log | pyformat`. Generally speaking, this is about separation of concerns: Engine invocation is a concern that could  (and should) be separated from output formatting, so both can be used independently.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I will try to make that available with pydflatex (should be easy, because it is already what happens inside pydflatex, first execution, then log parsing). Good point.

Comment: @Daniel I implemented (parts of) your suggestion in the new version of pydflatex.

Comment: ah, the new `-l` switch? Looks good, I will give it a try next week.

Comment: Olivier, I have tried it. Some remarks: I have a "standard" MacPorts python installation. (1) I had to install the `argparse` package, which probably should be listed in the dependencies. (2) It took me a while to figure that the package name for `termstyle` is actually `python-termstyle`, which should be mentioned for the uninspired. (3) On my first try I only got a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 91944-91949: unsupported Unicode code range` (in nice red color, though :-). The respective character was an `ü`. Missing UTF8 support is a show stopper, though.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for the feedback! argparse is part of standard Python distros > 2.7. UTF-8 is supported, but the log has to be in utf-8. If yours is, please send it to me (or, better, the tex file), or file an issue on github. Thanks again!

Comment: I have investigated the issue: Even though the input file is UTF8 and my locale settings are as well, `pdflatex` seems to generate a LATIN1-encoded log file. I have raised a [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131238/3751) about this.

Comment: Olivier, according to egreg's answer to my new question, it seems that there is a problem: The output format in the LaTeX log is in the respective font encoding (basically a stream of arbitrary bytes), so it is not valid to assume any specific encoding :-/

Comment: `pydflatex` now works even if the log is not encoded in utf-8.

Comment: This is unmaintained, right?

Answer (score 10):

I have used [rubber-info](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~beffara/soft/rubber/) and it is the best TeX error parser I have seen. The package is not actively maintained though. I have it report error through [growl](http://growl.info/) as in this screenshot:

[image: TeX error report through growl]

Comment: Great. Do I have to install rubber to get this to work, or can I just \usepackage something?

Comment: Rubber is a Python script, not a Latex package. You install rubber and simply run "rubber -Wall foo.tex" instead of something like "pdflatex foo; bibtex foo; pdflatex foo".

Comment: rubber is similar to latexmk. but you can use rubber-info to parse the log and continue using any compilation process you are using already.

Comment: Great.  I will check it out.  I tried installing with macports, which lists Tex as a dependency, so I was avoiding the huge install:


[~] port deps rubber:
Library Dependencies: python26
Runtime Dependencies: texlive

Comment: I ignore macports entirely.

Comment: @Leo: I didn't know the package, it looks great!  I like Growl :-)

Comment: @Arthur: thanks. I actually have emacs running as a server and the error is reported to emacs from another machine where a cron build script is watching over my git repo. Then emacs sends out the msg to growl.

Answer (score 5):

This is a comparison of the existing methods (plus a new suggestion by me below)

---

If you come across this question, you most likely want to quickly find the parts that you're interested in in the log file/output.

(the question itself only concern terminal output (stdout), but the errors/messages are in both the log file and terminal)

In my experience, the parts that you're possibly interested in are

- (most frequent) The errors raised by TeX.
- (less frequent, only if you do some TeX programming) Debug error messages printed by `\show`, `\showtokens`, `\tl_show:n`, `\regex_show:n` or similar.
- The warnings produced by TeX.
- Whether it can parse an existing file. (so you don't need to change your existing compilation command)

The table below compares the tools, with respect to the conditions above. *The first line is my new suggestion*.

The file in (7) is used.

| Tool | On error | On `\show` (3) | On warning | Parse log file |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `texfot cat a.log` | Configurable | Configurable | Continue | Yes |
| [`pulp a.log`](https://github.com/dmwit/pulp) | Configurable | ? | Configurable | Yes |
| `xelatex a.tex` | Prompt (4) | Prompt | Continue | No |
| `xelatex a.tex < /dev/null` | Stop | Stop | Continue | No |
| `latexmk [-g] a.tex` | Stop | Stop | Continue | No |
| `texfot xelatex a.tex` | Stop | Stop | Continue | Partial (6) |
| `xelatex a.tex < <(yes "")` | Continue | Continue | Continue | No |
| `latexmk [-g] -latexoption=-interaction=nonstopmode a.tex` | Continue | Continue | Continue | No |
| `texfot xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode a.tex` | Continue | Continue | Continue | Partial |
| `xelatex -interaction batchmode` | Hide and continue | Hide and continue | Hide | No |
| `latexmk -silent [-g] -latexoption=-interaction=nonstopmode a.tex` | Hide and continue | Hide and continue | Hide | No |
| `xelatex -interaction batchmode` with manual `\nonstopmode` ... `\batchmode` | Hide and continue (1) | Configurable | Hide | No |
| `rubber-info a.tex` | Configurable | Hide | Configurable | Yes |
| `pplatex -i a.log` (5) | Configurable | Hide | Configurable | Yes |
| `silence` package | ? | ? | ? | No |
| `pydflatex a.tex` | ? | ? | ? | ? |

(1): The user could wrap it manually, but it requires knowing where the error is in the first place.
(2): About `texfot --interactive xelatex a.tex`: The flag doesn't have any effect, see [pdflatex bash script to supress all output except error messages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27878/pdflatex-bash-script-to-supress-all-output-except-error-messages/165518#165518)
(3): The "Stop" case can always be converted to "Continue".  See [How can I make TeX stop on the first error, but do not stop on \show (or \tl_show:n)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621919/how-can-i-make-tex-stop-on-the-first-error-but-do-not-stop-on-show-or-tl-sho/621935#621935)  (disclaimer: my question)
(4): See [How can one stop LaTeX compilation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147346/how-can-one-stop-latex-compilation) for what to do with the prompt.
(5): May requires compilation from source if the provided binary does not work. Supports cmake.
(6): "Partial" means being able to run the compiler with any option, but requires re-run to filter.
(7): The example file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def \a {123}
\show \a
\tl_show:N \a
\tl_analysis_show:n {123}
\ExplSyntaxOff

Some example formula x^2+1=0
\end{document}
```

Regardless of the method, because LaTeX log file is relatively unstructured, any solution that parses the log file is subject to error.

---

Looks like [Pulp](https://github.com/dmwit/pulp) is not mentioned in the other answers. This is a quote from its README:

> ## What is pulp?
>
> Do you find LaTeX's output too voluminous? Do you wish it would get straight to the point and just tell you the errors and where they occurred? When you see this:
>
> ```
> Underfull \hbox (badness 3679) in paragraph at lines 278--282
> []\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 Shin-Cheng Mu, Zhen-jiang Hu, and
>  []
>
> [278]
> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 318--323
> []\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 Yingfei Xiong,
>  []
>
> ) [279] (./paper.aux)
>
> LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
>
>  ) )
> (\end occurred when \iftrue on line 2 was incomplete) 
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>  14398 strings out of 495035
>  257795 string characters out of 6181701
>  330613 words of memory out of 5000000
>  17235 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
>  23715 words of font info for 95 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
>  14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>  66i,21n,72p,680b,1562s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
> </usr/share/texlive/texmf-
> dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/f
> onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/
> type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/
> public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
> /amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
> nts/cm/cmmi6.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
> cmmi7.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.p
> fb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></us
> r/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share
> /texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb></usr/share/texlive
> /texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-d
> ist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/font
> s/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type
> 1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/publ
> ic/amsfonts/cm/cmss8.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
> onts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
> m/cmsy6.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7
> .pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy8.pfb></
> usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></usr/sh
> are/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti12.pfb></usr/share/te
> xlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti8.pfb></usr/share/texlive/t
> exmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-d
> ist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-di
> st/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb>
> Output written on paper.pdf (285 pages, 1369913 bytes).
> PDF statistics:
>  1660 PDF objects out of 1728 (max. 8388607)
>  1107 compressed objects within 12 object streams
>  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
>  224 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
> ```
>
> ...do your eyes automatically skip to the line about cross-references without conscious effort? Then you need `pulp`. Compare LaTeX's spew with what `pulp` has to say about that file:
>
> ```
> ./delta.tex:133-133: LaTeX warning: Float too large for page by 4.64713pt on input line 133.
> ./delta.tex:2649-2649: LaTeX warning: Float too large for page by 74.48848pt on input line 2649.
> ./delta.tex:3817-3817: LaTeX warning: Float too large for page by 99.13847pt on input line 3817.
> ./delta.tex:3923-3923: wrapfig warning: Collision between wrapping environments on input line 3923.
> ./delta.tex:3925-3925: wrapfig warning: Stationary wrapfigure forced to float on input line 3925.
> ./delta.tex:3951-3951: wrapfig warning: Collision between wrapping environments on input line 3951.
> ./delta.tex:3954-3954: wrapfig warning: Stationary wrapfigure forced to float on input line 3954.
> ./skeleton_dissertation.tex:36-?: LaTeX warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
> 2-2: (\end occurred when \iftrue on line 2 was incomplete)
> ```
>
> Not only is the label warning more clearly highlighted, a number of other errors -- which were scrolled way the heck off the terminal ages ago if you were just using `pdflatex` -- are more clearly visible, together with information about which source file and line number caused the problem. (In fact, even messages which do not have a line number directly in them will have a "best guess" assigned to them by pulp to give you an idea of where in the file to start looking.)

Comment: Side note, texfot has the disadvantage that it does not show the full \errorcontextlines (only one line), so you can view the log later.

Comment: There are a few other ones e.g. [`texlogfilter`](https://ctan.org/pkg/texlogfilter) although I haven't used it. Now I just use vimtex's built-in filtering.

Answer (score 4):

Having read the answers, I ended up with this lightweight solution:

`pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode paper.tex 1> log || cat log`

Answer (score 2):

Consider also following tool:

**[Pretty Print LaTeX: pplatex](https://github.com/stefanhepp/pplatex)**

```
pplatex --cmd <yourlatexbinary> -q -- latexfile.tex
```

Based on the parser of kile.

Note about availability:
Not part of MikTex or TexLive and not contained in Debian/Ubuntu repositories and there is also no Mac OSX homebrew formula. However, custom installation is not difficult.
*Update 2016:* links on [github](https://github.com/stefanhepp/pplatex#download) to pre-compiled binaries for linux-x64 and windows are available.

Answer (score 2):

Today I got very tired of `pdflatex` trashing my console at each run.

So after too many years of compliance I wrote this script for my `.bashrc`.

```bash
# Compile tex file containing svg
svgtex () {
    pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -output-directory="out" \
        $1 1> /dev/null
    [[ $? = 0 ]] || echo `grep Error out/${$1/tex/log}`
}
```

I share it as OP asked for a script, and latexmk is not to be found on my distro. Defining a function in `.bashrc` works like an alias, except you can pass it arguments (e.g. filename=$1)

I pass the following options:

- `-shell-escape`: required to include svg files, which my defense slides contain
- `-halt-on-error`: stop killing the terminal by hanging in batchmode or whatever
- `-output-dir`: stop trashing the source directory with `.nav .toc .out .log .aux .snm` files... am I forgetting any?

I just use it as `svgtex file.tex` and no output is produced.

**N.B.** Although only `stdout` is redirected to `/dev/null`, no error messages are printed in case of failure, so it seems `pdflatex` does not use `stderr`. Hence the last line to check the return code `pdflatex` and print only error lines.

You can always do `less out/file.log` if you want to know all about it.

Answer (score 2):

On GNU/Linux I've found `texfot` to be the most reliable, and it comes packaged with TexLive.  It filters the output of the command you pass it:

```
texfot pdflatex …options your-document.tex
```

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165518/1551) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, there are many tools that may help with this. I have recently uploaded [texlogsieve](https://ctan.org/pkg/texlogsieve) to CTAN, which is my own attempt at a texlua script to filter the LaTeX log file. I like it :) . The main selling points are

1. Lots of options to choose what to show/hide;
2. Reliable line unwrapping;
3. Multi-line messages are treated as a single entity.

Note that it does *not* treat error messages specially (they are just dumped to the output together with the other unfiltered messages). Still, calling `texlogsieve -l unknown --no-page-delay --no-shipouts --no-summary LOGFILE` should give you something very close to "only error messages".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ltx2any`](https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any) to compile your document. This will not only compile your document, but also produce a summary of errors and warnings:

[image]