# Better error reporting in Latex?

Tags: compiling, errors, warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting the console output of Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/formatting-the-console-output-of-latex)

Is there a way to make Latex / PdfLatex less verbose?
Basically I would like to only get warnings, errors and one line summary with number of pages.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/formatting-the-console-output-of-latex?

Comment: Is this a good candidate for merging?