# Is there a bash wrapper for tex output?

Tags: bash

I am wondering if there is a bash tool available that I can pipe my latex output through and retrieve a more user-friendly output (i.e. file and line number of error). Currently, I am using a bash script to run pdflatex and bibtex. I develop in Atom and don't want to use any of the graphical Latex editors.

Comment: Maybe something here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10558/use-latexmk-to-filter-the-log-file

Answer (score 2):

There is `ltx2any` which will not only automatically compile your latex document but also produce a beautiful summary of any warnings and error messages (several different file formats are available). An example of the output from its website:

[image]

See https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any for more information

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to find the line numbers if you use `--file-line-error` then given `bb831.tex` looking like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


aaaa \zzzzz


bbbb }


\end{document}
```

The bash command line

```
pdflatex -interaction=scrollmode --file-line-error bb831 | grep -A2 '^\.[^\.]*\.tex:'
```

produces terminal output of just

```
./bb831.tex:6: Undefined control sequence.
l.6 aaaa \zzzzz

./bb831.tex:9: Too many }'s.
l.9 bbbb }
```