# pdflatex bash script to supress all output except error messages?

Tags: pdftex, errors, scripts

I have a bash script which I use to compile a file with pdflatex twice (to make sure it sorts out references properly, etc.). This is the 'latexbuild' script I use:

```
module load ctan
pdflatex --shell-escape --interaction=nonstopmode $1
bibtex $1
pdflatex --shell-escape --interaction=nonstopmode --interaction=batchmode $1
```

I would then call this script with `latexbuild test.tex`. It produces a lot of output which I would like to supress, except for the error messages which I'd like to see. Is there any way to only allow error messages to be displayed?

Comment: I think that the best you can get (without filtering) is the `-halt-on-error` flag, which stops on first error. Also two LaTeX passes may not be enough in general. And what about warning messages?

Comment: Yeah I mean warnings as well as errors. The KDE latex editor Kile somehow manages to do it, it has a small log window which only displays errors and warnings, but I can't figure out how to do that in a script

Comment: No. TeX does not distinguish between `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing the console output of LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/reducing-the-console-output-of-latex)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the `-file-line-error` option and then `grep` the output for something of that form `filename:##:error code` (Below I just use the regex `.*:[0-9]*:.*`. Works decently well on a few tests.

Note, `bibtex` is run on the `.aux` file not the `.tex` file. For it, using the `-terse` option is probably sufficient.

Lastly I have no idea what your `module load ctan` does (--I have no such program--), so I excluded it.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ARGUMENT="$1"
#determine aux name by stripping .tex suffix and adding .aux
AUXNAME="${ARGUMENT%.tex}.aux"
pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error "$ARGUMENT" | grep ".*:[0-9]*:.*" 
bibtex -terse "$AUXNAME"  
pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error "$ARGUMENT" | grep ".*:[0-9]*:.*"
```

You might want to play around with the `-A` and `-B` options to `grep` if you want some context surrounding the error messages, rather than just a single line.

I'd also play around with using if constructs or checking exit status to determine whether the last two steps should be done. (E.g., if an error is found in the first run, don't bother with the second, etc.) I can give more details if need be.

EDIT: Just saw your comment about warnings. The above will only catch true errors. I'm not sure there is a standard to warning messages, but grepping for the word "warning" might be good enough. so then it's something like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ARGUMENT="$1"
#determine aux name by stripping .tex suffix and adding .aux
AUXNAME="${ARGUMENT%.tex}.aux"
pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error "$ARGUMENT" | grep -i ".*:[0-9]*:.*\|warning" 
bibtex -terse "$AUXNAME"  
pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error "$ARGUMENT" | grep -i ".*:[0-9]*:.*\|warning"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. I changed `grep ".*:[0-9]*:.*"` to `egrep ".*:[0-9]*:.*|LaTeX Warning:"` so that it looks for warnings as well as errors.

Answer (score 31):

[The `texfot` Perl script](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/support/texfot/) by Karl Berry has been recently added to TeX Live; the command line

```
> texfot pdflatex eddy
```

where `eddy.tex` is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

A purposely overfull line
\makebox[1.1\textwidth]{x}

And an error
\abcdefghi

\end{document}
```

will produce the following output on the terminal:

```
/usr/texbin/texfot: invoking: pdflatex eddy
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
Overfull \hbox (156.0012pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--6
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \abcdefghi
! Emergency stop.
l.8 \abcdefghi
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on eddy.log.
```

Although the documentation asserts that the `--interactive` option allows for stopping at errors, this doesn't seem to work (maybe this will be fixed in a next release).

The “real” terminal output is available in `$TMPDIR/fot` or `/tmp/fot` if the `TMPDIR` environment variable is not set.

Comment: I have been looking for something like this for so long. Latex generates so much output. Very nice. Thank also to Karl Berry.

Comment: Can I suppress the warnings while keeping the errors?

Comment: @Diaa Not with `texfot`, I believe.

Comment: Pretty useful! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The [`silence` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence) provides a means for suppressing LaTeX package and class warnings and errors. For example, the command

```
\WarningFilter{latex}{Marginpar on page}
```

would suppress all warnings produced by `latex` that start with "`Marginpar on page`...". It is not always perfect, but it seems like something that might help in your case. You could also suppress *all* warnings (or errors) using `\WarningsOff` (or `\ErrorsOff`). Consider reading the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/silence/silence-doc.pdf) for more of the filtering options.

Comment: I think he wants to suppress everything _but_ errors and warnings. This package seems to do just the opposite

Answer (score 1):

**Newb** attempt that seems to be working on a few simple examples:

```
pdflatex a.tex | perl -0777 -ne 'print m/\n! .*?\nl\.\d.*?\n.*?(?=\n)/gs'
```

supposes that all errors are of form:

```
! Cryptic explanation
<maybe more cryptic explanations>
l.123 Undefined \asdfqwer
                          very very very very long line.
```

Please correct away.

**EDIT**

As answered by egreg after I posted, [texfot](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/support/texfot/) seems to be a super advanced version of this attempt also based on "heuristic" regex filtering. Not in TeX Live 2013 ISO, but prefer that if you can use it.

Comment: An error does not necessarily start with an `!`

Comment: I assumed that because of: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Errors_and_Warnings#Error_messages. So that info is totally wrong? Or is just a common convention?

Comment: If you are using a TeXLive based system you can add `file_line_error_style = t` to the base `texmf.cnf` (the one in `/<year>/`), then there are no leading `!`. But `texfot` works just fine.

Comment: @daleif I was going to say: add that to an answer, but egreg was faster =)

Comment: I only tested it after reading egregs answer. Had a look at what `texfot` does, it is explicitly looking for certain strings from the program output.