# Warnings and errors highlighting when compiling in Bash environment

Tags: errors, color, warnings, highlighting, syntax

I'm processing a large document, using `Latexmk` in a `Bash` environment. It would be very helpful if error and warning messages were somehow highlighted or coloured, in order to facilitate spotting them. Specially when dealing with `Biber` and `Biblatex`, catching the warnings on time is important, as they won't normally stop the compilation process when something comes out.

Until recently, I was using the `LateX` bundle in `TextMate`, which helped showing only the most important messages (errors, warnings, inputs, includes, etc.) See here:

[image: TextMate compiling]

But I became deceptioned by that bundle and now I am compiling everything directly in the shell (`Bash` in Linux or Os X), as it gives me better control.

(Of course I could open the `.log` file, and configure the editor to search for/highlight these items, but I was thinking of "in the fly" highlighting/colouring.)

Is it possible to colour-code the `stdout` of `latexmk` (or in general of the `*Tex` bins)?

Comment: I use a few different scripts to help with my compiling; the answer I gave [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52890/6621) focuses on a `vim` implementation, but it can easily port to other editors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always pipe the output through something that does colour, one simple example produces

[image]

From running the command

```
  pdflatex tb67 2>&1 | grep --color=auto  "LaTeX Warning"
```

on a file with a `ref{jjj}` undefined reference which I inserted for demonstration purposes.

Comment: And is there another way of bashing the output so as to show all messages in the default colour, plus the errors/warnings in red only? The `grep` function is great, but is filters everything else out.

Comment: add -C1000 to get up to a 1000 lines of context (ie non-matching lines) around the coloured lines

Comment: Unfortunatedly it doesn't work well with `latexmk`. I don't know why, but I have to press `return` for each pass to proceed.

Comment: Is it picking up the exit status from grep rather then pdftex grep --help says Exit status is 0 if any line is selected, 1 otherwise; sorry never used latexmk (and i'm on cygwin not a real *x operating system so can't really test too well:-)

Answer (score 3):

I use the following line in my make files:

```
pdflatex filename.tex 2>&1 | grep --color -E "Warning|Missing|$"
```

This should highlight "Warning"s and show all other lines as well, since "|$" part of pattern means "Or end of a line".

Answer (score 3):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I can only leave an answer, although it is not an actual answer.

You may want to try [texfot](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texfot), which generates message like this:

```
/usr/texbin/texfot: invoking: pdflatex eddy
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
Overfull \hbox (156.0012pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--6
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \abcdefghi
! Emergency stop.
l.8 \abcdefghi
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on eddy.log.
```

as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165518).