# Execute lualatex within bash script placed inside cgi-bin

Tags: luatex, bash

have a cgi-script which generates a *.tex file based on inputs from the browser. i would like to generate a pdf and download it.

however the command doesnt execute and i get a fail message

```
if lualatex -interaction batchmode 3.tex                                                                                                                                 
  then 
          echo"yo" 
  else    
          echo "fail"
          exit 2
  fi
```

the 3.tex file is perfect and lualtex executes when directly executed from terminal.

i have used this [also](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27878/pdflatex-bash-script-to-supress-all-output-except-error-messages)
but could get it too work

kindly help

Comment: is luatex in the PATH available in your cgi-bin environment?

Comment: found it not present

Comment: stick echo $PATH and `type luaflatex`  into the script and see what comes out, or simply use luatex by its full path `/usr/local/texlive/20..../bin/lualatex` or whatever is allowed in your cgi environment, if the web server runs off a virtual root is tex even installed?

Comment: thank you sir, it started working after adding the full path. could you please guide as to how to add it to the  PATH available in your cgi-bin environment

Comment: just put `export PATH=/usr/local./txliv/whevere/it/is:$PATH` as teh first line to add the texlive bin to the path

Answer (score 3):

cgi-bin jobs do not run in your usual user enviromment so you may need to access luatex by full path

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/whatever/lualatex 3.tex
```

or add the bin directory to your path

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/whatever:$PATH

lualatex 3.tex
```