# pdflatex command output only warnings

Tags: pdftex, warnings

Is there a way to run pdflatex such that it outputs only the warning messages?

Thanks.

Comment: On my system `pdflatex --help` gives the available options for pdflatex and what you are asking for is not listed as an option. On the other hand,`pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode <filename> | grep Warning` would do roughly want you want on a unix-like system (I have no idea if there is a similar command for windows).

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of all warnings in your document, you could use the building [ltx2any](https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any). It parses the .log file and creates neat list with all error messages and warnings in different file formats.

One example of what such a list can look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`pdflatex` does not seem to support only outputting warnings.

Using `pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode <filename> | grep Warning` (due to @Andrew) has the disadvantage of cutting off warnings that span across multiple lines.

Instead, I am currently using this command:

```sh
pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode <filename> | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1}/warning|!/,/^$/;'
```

It runs `pdflatex` in `nonstopmode` (continues on errors), and then filters the output using `awk`. The filter captures `warning` (case insensitive) and exclamation marks (sometimes used to indicate an error).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [texfot tool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165518/1551) to filter pdflatex' output:

```
texfot pdflatex …options your-document.tex
```