# Make \input path work irrespective of from where latex is ran

Tags: input, paths

In the directory `/user/`, I have a file `header.tex`.

In the file `/user/dir/main.tex`, I use `\input{../header.tex}`.

When I run `pdflatex main.tex` from `/user/dir`, everything works fine. But if I run`pdflatex dir/main.tex` from `/user`, I get the `File ../header.tex not found` error.

Is it possible to define `input` with respect to the file on which `pdflatex` is run (here, `/user/dir/main.tex`), so that `pdflatex` would work irrespective of the folder from which it is ran?

Comment: no it is built in to tex that input and default output are relative to the working directory not the directory with the file but you can always write a wrapper script that takes a file path, cds to the file director and then runs pdflatex, or just use `\input{header}` and arrange that `/user` is in TEXINPUTS then it will work from anywhere just as `article.cls` gets input wherever you are as it is in TEXINPUTS

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, I wrote an answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is elaborated from David Carlisle's comment, in case it helps someone. Since `\input` cannot be changed in such a way, there are basically two strategies:

- Let latex now about the file globally, ideally by adding `header.tex` to `~/texmf/tex/latex/<username>`, or to the variable `TEXINPUTS`. More details on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/93733/34258). In my case, I wanted my files to be self-contained in a single directory (for `git`), so I went with the second option.
- Write a script that goes into each directory, run `pdflatex` and so on. This is the option I used.

First, I generate a list of all `tex` files and store if in `listOfTeX.txt` (to be ran from the parent directory):

```
find . -type f \( -iname "$.tex" \) >> listOfTeX.txt
```

Then,

```
while read FILE; do 
    printf "\n ----> $FILE\n"; # prints the file path and name
    DIR=$(dirname "$FILE");    # extracts the directory
    cd $DIR;                   # goes to that directory
    texfot pdflatex $(basename "$FILE") | grep "error";  # run pdflatex
    cd ../;                 # goes back to the parent directory (in my case)
done < listOfTeX.txt
```

Explanations on the line `texfot pdflatex $(basename "$FILE") | grep "error";` : `texfot` is used to reduce the output of `pdflatex`, see [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165518/34258). Then I use `grep "error"` to display only the errors. That allows to directly find the problematic files and paths. To be adjusted to your needs of course (same for `cd ../`).

Comment: Actually there is this way [Full path of current file - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42417/full-path-of-current-file)