# Latex compile reduce command line output

Tags: errors, winedt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reducing the console output of LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/reducing-the-console-output-of-latex)

Any time I compile a tex document I get a ton of command line outputs about loading sty's and other useless information for me. How can I stop all this information and just display the errors themselves. Basically only stuff having to do with after `\begin{document}` It will be helpful because in WinEdt it always requires me to scroll down to to find the errors (which are somewhere in the middle).

```
Command Line:   lualatex.exe "doc.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\Documents    
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011080216 (rev 4277) 
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
LuaTeX adaptation of babel <v3.8l-luatex-1.4> and hyphenation patterns for engl
ish, loaded.
("D:/Program Files/Text/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/book.cls"
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("D:/Program Files/Text/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo"))
("D:/Program Files/Text/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty"

....
....
....

LuaLaTeX failed to create a pdf file.
For possible explanations start the command from the Command Prompt...
```

Comment: @doncherry: Not quite a duplicate, since this question asks about reducing the output in WinEdt.

Comment: I'd say this does look like a dupe, as the solutions (such as they are) are at the (La)TeX level, at least in the main. @Uiy, does the linked answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something that is called "run modes" in TeX. You can set the mode in two ways (I illustrate on a useful `\batchmode`):

1. Call LaTeX by `pdflatex -interaction batchmode myfile.tex` -- this way, the program prints only some initial version information and then turns quiet, even for errors. You have to find all the information in your log file then.
2. Put `\batchmode` by the beginning of your document if you want that document to run in batch mode every time.

The overview of TeX run modes can be found for instance [at this TUG.org page](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#batchmode-rp).

Comment: This is basically the idea but you need to use the modes multiple times in a doc. Use `\batchmode` and `interation batchmode` at the start to get rid of all the startup messages. Turn the output back on by using `\scrollmode` or something else when you need to see the messages.

Answer (score 5):

Not directly an answer, but perhaps interesting nonetheless.

WinEdt has some "error management" to make it easier to find errors. Say I have a document looking like

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\begin{document}
\Section{Whatnot}
Lorem ipsum.
\section{Notwhat}
srn & srhogm
\end{document}
```

This will obviously generate errors, due to the misspelled `\section` and the unescaped ampersand (&). If I compile this, hitting enter to continue compilation despite the errors, I see something like the below.

[image]

On the toolbar above the bottom panel, there are several buttons, including the one circled here:

[image]

Click this and the toolbar will change:

[image]

Now you can jump between errors using the arrows on the left side of the toolbar. If the exclamation mark-button at the far left is "active", warnings will be included in this. In the above document I got one warning (Unused global option [demo]) and two errors. Clicking the right-pointing arrow twice I get to the first of the errors. The line in the log file, as well as the corresponding location in the document, is highlighted.

[image]