# Reducing output garbage

Tags: terminal-output

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reducing the console output of LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/reducing-the-console-output-of-latex)

```
running: C:\Program Files\Text\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\lualatex.exe -interaction=batchmodesrc-specials main.tex 
lualatex.exe> This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012060719 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) 
lualatex.exe>  \write18 enabled.
lualatex.exe> Chapter 1.
lualatex.exe> [1{C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2]
lualatex.exe> [3] [4] [5] [6] ("C:/Program Files/Text/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/t1cmss.fd")
lualatex.exe> [7] [8]
lualatex.exe> Overfull \hbox (12.08553pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 69--271
lualatex.exe>  [] 
lualatex.exe> [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14]
lualatex.exe> ("C:/Program Files/Text/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/inconsolata/t1fi4.fd") [15]
lualatex.exe> [16] [17] [18]
lualatex.exe> Chapter 2.
lualatex.exe> 
lualatex.exe> 
lualatex.exe> 
lualatex.exe> 
lualatex.exe> Time: 8s 855ms
lualatex.exe>
```

Is the output of my latex after compiling a document with several images included using about 20 packages(tikz, several custom packages, etc...)

I would like to reduce the output even further. Specifically the `t1fi4.fd`, `t1cmss.fd`, and `pdftex.map` line as that is garbage to me. I guess it has to do with fonts and someone left in a `message` that outputs that junk to the console.

The `[]` are not so bad and I believe have to do with the included images. With the `.fd`'s gone they will not look so bad and might be useful for a sort of progress report. It would be nice if I could make it skip a few counts though(like every 5 instead of every 1).

The overfull box is sort of annoying but I can fix that easy enough.

Does anyone recognize where the `.fd`/`.map` lines are coming from and/or know how to get rid of them?

(I've disabled all outputting messages I could think of but these always show up and break the flow of the program for no good reason)

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need this output to be this streamlined? The [3] printouts count through the pages of the document as they get generate; usually included images show up as referenced files, much like the `.fd` and `.map` files do here.

Comment: @MikaelVejdemo-Johansson Because I don't wanna see garbage that is irrelevant to the project. those lines I mentioned are absolutely useless. Why do I need to know that some `.fd` is included? What's the point? To let me know I included the file? Do I need to see it every compilation and have it break the flow of the console output just to let me know each time it was included? (I think I got it the first time) If I need more verbose output I'll enable it by not using `batchmode`.

Answer (score 7):

This is *not* garbage, but very important information. All text files that are input are recorded, along with the image files that are imported and included in the final PDF.

A `.fd` file contains the necessary info to use a font; in your case `t1cmss.fd` contains the information for European Modern Sans (T1 encoding) and `t1fi4.fd` is for Inconsolata. TeX has no way to distinguish between input files containing your document proper or auxiliary files such as `.fd`: it simply logs every input file. In particular it logs the `pdftex.map` file and it's *very* important to know which one has been loaded in case of problems with the pairing between `.tfm` files and `.pfb`/`.pfa` files.

The `[]` annotation that you find is simply a very scanty representation of the reported overfull box; if you had set in the preamble

```
\showboxdepth=10 \showboxbreadth=100
```

you'd have seen more than `[]` (LaTeX sets the two parameters to zero).

You may want to examine the `texloganalyser` script that's included in TeX Live (and possibly in MiKTeX). But removing this from the terminal output requires changing the sources of TeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: Huh? Why has this answer been downvoted so often?