# How can one stop LaTeX compilation?

Tags: compiling, linux

When I start to compile a TeX file with wrong syntax, LaTeX complains. The first thing that I try is to stop (kill) the LaTeX compilation. However, nothing works. I have tried `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+q`, `quit`, `exi`t, `q`, `quit()`... At the end I need to use top-command from Linux to kill the process. Is there a civilized way to kill LaTeX?

Comment: Which editor you are using? It will have some options.

Comment: With most command-line programs, EOF (ctrl+d) is normally a good first guess

Comment: On windows, Ctrl-Z will normally work.

Comment: In TeXnicCenter (under Windows) it allows you to [stop a build](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nKass.png).

Answer (score 73):

**Personal Statement**

I am a command-line human and (blissfully) ignorant of LaTeX IDEs (front ends) and editor specific compilations. I do my typing in [emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) using [AUCTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUCTeX), and compile in a terminal. So, my answer is focused in the command-line area.

---

**The Solution**

Actually, there is a *civilized way to kill LaTeX*, as asked by you.

Enter `x` at the prompt, then press `Enter`. Pressing `Ctrl-d` may be even faster. Most terminals send en end-of-file with this keystroke, which makes LaTeX react in the same way as if `x` was entered.

(The above two are not exactly identical. In case of `x`, LaTeX will tell about, "No pages of output...". In case of `Ctrl-d`,  it will be treated as, "Emergency stop. .... Fatal error". I wish I could be more specific about the nuances of these two.)

Consider the following example.
I have intentionally introduced a syntax error in my file.

[image]

LaTeX stops and complains about  "Undefined control sequence". I type `x` and then
press `Enter`. There is a clean exit.

If I press `Ctrl-d` under a similar situation, there is again an exit, with slightly different messages.

[image]

If you want to know more about your available options, enter `?` while in the LaTeX prompt and press `Enter`.
This gives,

> ```
> ? ?
> Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
> R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
> I to insert something, E to edit your file,
> 1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
> H for help, X to quit.
> ```

---

**Additional but Helpful**

Additionally, learning the following helps (may be Linux/command line specific).

- To interrupt a long compilation, press `Ctrl-c`, that gives you the prompt mentioned above.
- If LaTeX is waiting for an input file which does not exist,

> ```
> ! I can't find file `nosuchfile.tex'.
> l.5 \input nosuchfile.tex
>
> (Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
> Please type another input file name:
> ```

press `Ctrl-d`.

Comment: Front ends (or IDE, if you prefer) usually call the typesetting engine with the `--interaction=nonstopmode` command line option (or equivalent method).

Comment: `x`+`Enter` works for Notepad++ too! This has bugged me forever

Answer (score 17):

If you run `pdflatex` as

```
pdflatex -halt-on-error file.tex
```

it will stop after the first error.

Comment: Thanks! This works for xelatex as well!

Answer (score 7):

I'm late to the party, but I was wondering the same thing and found this answer in my search, so I thought I'd post it.

If you're using `AUCTeX`, the command `TeX-kill-job` is what you need. By default it's bound to `C-c C-k`.