# Is it possible to print the warning/error - log?

Tags: errors, warnings

Is it possible to print the Errors and Warning - log?

Because I want to have a better overview over the logged warnings in a separate document

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Note that I find the linked question better suited than the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/reducing-the-console-output-of-latex which is suggested as a duplicate of the first question, although both provide useful information. From both questions `texfot` (possibly combined with a redirect into a file if you want to store the warnings and errors) seems to do what you want.

Comment: @Steven Have a look at ltx2any https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662010/36296

Comment: I'll try to explain how the duplicates apply to your question: you can go into a terminal and type `texfot pdflatex yourfile.tex > allwarnings.txt`. This will run pdflatex on your file and store the warnings and errors in the file allwarnings.txt. I tested this on Linux and it works, however the manual of `texfot` mentions that it may not work in Windows. Also, for some multi-line warnings only the first line is shown in the output.

Comment: I also tried various other tools mentioned in the other questions, like `rubber-info` and `texloganalyser`, which also work but suffer from similar problems as `texfot`, i.e., not everything is captured correctly. This is however a very hard to solve problem because LaTeX doesn't use `stderr` properly. Also GUI editors like TeXstudio are known to display partial or misformatted error messages.