# Controlling console log output

Tags: logging

While processing a latex file, log output to console is usually smaller than what you can find in the log file, so that you can spot errors more easily.

Yet, I am not able to understand how I can have control on what is sent to the console, as log output.

Consider for example the following console log output for my file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./wip.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nopageno/nopageno.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmtools.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-patch.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/parseargs.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-kv.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-autoref.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/aliasctr.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-listof.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-restate.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-amsthm.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-italian/italian.ldf))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tocbibind/tocbibind.sty

Package tocbibind Note: Using chapter style headings, unless overridden.

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/makeidx.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/soulutf8/soulutf8.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/soul/soul.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmdef-shaded.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/shadethm/shadethm.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./wip.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty)) (./wip.out) (./wip.out)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex
/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./wip.toc) [1] (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmtt.fd) [1]
Lezione 1.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/ts1lmr.fd) [2] [3] [4] [5]
Lezione 2.
[6] [7] [8]
Lezione 3.
[9] [10] [11] [12]
Lezione 4.
[13] [14]
Lezione 5.
[15] [16] [17] [18]
Lezione 6.
[19] [20] [21]
Lezione 7.
[22] [23] [24]
Lezione 8.
[25] [26] [27]
Lezione 9.
[28] [29] [30] [31]
Lezione 10.
[32] [33] [34] [35] [36]
Lezione 11.
[37] [38]
Lezione 12.
[39] [40] [41] [42]
Lezione 13.
[43] [44] [45] [46] [47]
Lezione 14.
[48] [49] [50] [51] [52]
Lezione 15.
[53] [54]
Lezione 16.
[55] [56] [57] (./wip.aux) ){/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathsy.enc}{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-rm.enc}{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathit.enc}{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}{/usr/share/te
xmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathex.enc}{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ts1.enc}</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmbxi10.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmex10.pfb
></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmmi10.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmmi12.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmmi8.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/publi
c/lm/lmr12.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr17.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr6.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr7.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr8.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/ty
pe1/public/lm/lmri12.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmsy10.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmsy6.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmsy8.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmtt12.pfb></usr/share
/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb>
Output written on wip.pdf (59 pages, 475943 bytes).
SyncTeX written on wip.synctex.
Transcript written on wip.log.
```

It is 113 lines, opposed to the 902 lines of the log file, so it is surely more readable than the log file itself.

Yet, I find all the font lines quite distracting and, which is worse, quite useless: I would happily get rid of them.

My question, then, is:

- in particular: how can I get rid of those lines?
- in general: how can I control what is sent as log output to the console?

Comment: there is very little control, basically things are sent to the terminal or log, and you can set `\tracingonline=1` so stuff that goes to the log goes to the terminal, and that's about it.

Comment: funny I just suggested in an answer yesterday someone test with luatex rather than xetex specifically so they get those font paths logged. One person's distracting noise is another's main information.....

Comment: There are some filtering postprocessors, a simple one is texfot (run as `texfot pdflatex yourfile.tex`) which promises to "show only useful messages" and is customizable.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/reducing-the-console-output-of-latex/604673 for an overview of different available tools.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like there is no solution to this question, just workarounds. In particular, the workaround `\batchmode / \scrollmode` described in the link provided by @Marijn applies quite nicely to my particular problem: I can live with that.