# Why am I getting a `3 is a bad bad` error?

Tags: bibtex, errors, environment-variables

After upgrading from TeX Live 2022 to TeX Live 2023, when running `bibtex`, `bibtex8`, or `bibtexu` in TeX Live 2023, I get this error for any input file:

```
3 is a bad bad
```

bibtex does not produce any output. What causes this error?

Answer (score 1):

`bad` is a variable in `bibtex` used for reporting "constants" that do not meet certain constraints. The only "good" `bad` is `0`. A `bad` value of 3 means [`max_print_line >= buf_size`](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/bibtex.web?revision=57915&view=markup#l466), which is not allowed.

Beginning in TeX Live 2023, [`bibtex` now gets the `max_print_line` "constant" from the environment](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/bibtex.ch?r1=63237&r2=63238&). So if you have the `max_print_line` environment variable set to ≥20000, [as suggested in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1193/1662), you will now trigger this error, which you wouldn't have seen before. It does not appear that you can set `buf_size` with an environment variable in the same way.

If you set `max_print_line=19999`, the error goes away.

If you are trying to understand how this happens in `bibtex` works by reading the PDF version of its source produced with weave that comes with TeX Live, you may be more confused because the code reading the environment variables is not there, nor is an initial `buf_size` value of 20000. All of these things occur in the [bibtex.ch](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/bibtex.ch?revision=68508&view=markup) change file, which makes various patches.